# What I call 'release' instead of 'close' on a NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I'm done with a popup NSWindow, I invoke the following lines of code:

```
if (imageDroppedActionPopup) {
    [[self window] removeChildWindow:imageDroppedActionPopup];
    [imageDroppedActionPopup orderOut:nil];
    [imageDroppedActionPopup close];
    imageDroppedActionPopup = nil;
}
```

I'm now wondering if I can replace

```
[imageDroppedActionPopup close];
```

with

```
[imageDroppedActionPopup release];
```

It seems to work correctly. But I was wondering if it is correct.

The reason I'm doing this, is that if I use close for some reason the app focus come back to the main document window, and not the current NSWindowController window, which is the above mentioned popup parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `close`. Calling `orderOut:` will close the window. You should do this before removing it as a child window. This will prevent the window ordering problems that you're seeing.

Just do this:

```
if (imageDroppedActionPopup) 
{
    [imageDroppedActionPopup orderOut:nil];
    [[self window] removeChildWindow:imageDroppedActionPopup];
    [imageDroppedActionPopup release];
    imageDroppedActionPopup = nil;
}
```

Note that I'm still calling `release` on the window, before setting it to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

`close` removes the window from screen, `release` decreases object's retain counter and may or may not cause it to be deallocated.

It seems to work because being deallocated implies being removed from screen, but these methods can never replace one another. Even if you are the only owner you can never be sure that `release` will cause immediate deallocation (and therefore nor immediate disappearance of the window), because the window might be temporary retained by someone else.

When you need the window to close, call `close`. And you must only call `release` on objects which you have retained, allocated or copied, strictly according to memory management rules.

Considering that replacing `close` with `release` did not cause crash, I think you need both.

Comment: OK. Do you maybe know why closing the popup window, causes the current window to move back behind the main document window ? You can see my code in the question...